# SQL Server - two joins to the same table on the same column

Tags: sql-server

I was curious if it's possible to join two tables to recive something like below.

```
**superTable**

id | project 
1     aaa         
2     bbb    

**approvedTable**
id | statusStep | Emp
1     BossMan    Gregor
1     FirstMate  Hans

**notApprovedTable**
id | statusStep | Emp
1      Sailor     Julia
1      Sr.Sailor  Dave
```

I wish to join both tables 'approvedTable' and 'notApprovedTable' to superTable on id to have something like this

```
   id | project | approvedStep |   Emp    | notApprovedStep | Emp
   1     aaa       BossMan        Gregor        null          null
   1     aaa       FirstMate      Hans          null          null
   1     aaa       null           null          Sailor        Julia    
   1     aaa       null           null          Sr.Sailor     Dave
```

if i do a simple join it create something like this

```
   id | project | approvedStep |   Emp    | notApprovedStep | Emp
   1     aaa       BossMan        Gregor        Sailor        Julia
   1     aaa       FirstMate      Hans          Sailor        Julia 
   1     aaa       BossMan        Gregor        Sr.Sailor     Dave
   1     aaa       FirstMate      Hans          Sr.Sailor     Dave
```

Answer (score 0):

UNION may help you

```
SELECT s.ID,s.project,a.statusStep approvedStep,a.Emp,NULL AS notApprovedStep, NULL AS notApprovedEmp
FROM  superTable s
INNER JOIN approvedTable a ON s.ID=a.ID 
UNION 
SELECT s.ID,s.project,NULL AS approvedStep,NULL AS Emp,na.statusStep AS notApprovedStep,na.Emp AS notApprovedEmp
FROM  superTable s
INNER JOIN notApprovedTable na ON s.ID=na.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Two queries the results of which you glue with `UNION ALL`:

```
select s.id, s.project, 
       a.statusstep as approved_step, a.emp as approved_emp, 
       null as not_approved_step, null as not_approved_emp
from supertable s
join approvedtable a on a.id = s.id
union all
select s.id, s.project, 
       null as approved_step, null as approved_emp, 
       na.statusstep as not_approved_step, na.emp as not_approved_emp
from supertable s
join notapprovedtable na on na.id = s.id
```